# Creating table via SQL Command Line, invalid identifier

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I'm currently learning SQL and I've installed oracle 11g express on my system. I'm trying to create a table however when I try to run the below command I get the following Error Message:

ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00904 : invalid identifier

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECTS (
    proID       NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    Desc        CHAR(20),
    sDate       DATE,
    eDate       DATE,
    Budget      NUMBER(7,2),
    maxStaff    NUMBER(2)
);
```

Can anybody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for all the replies, I ran this command succesfully:

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECTS (
    proID       NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    description CHAR(20),
    sDate       DATE,
    eDate       DATE,
    Budget      NUMBER(7,2),
    maxStaff    NUMBER(2)
);
```

Really Appreciate the fast replies!

Chris

Comment: DESC is a reserved word, short for DESCENDING in ORDER BT

Comment: try to use [Desc] instead Desc

Comment: Also, consider not abbreviating your column names. You have 30 characters to work with and I recommend using all of them. Expand `sDate` to `START_DATE` for example. It will make view/API creation much easier to read.

Comment: Look here for the list of reserved keywords in Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm

Comment: @KhurramAli, `[identifier]` is non-standard, used by Microsoft SQL Server, not Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `DESC` in as a column name. While you can use it you will have to encompass it in quotes:

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECTS (
    proID       NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    "Desc"        CHAR(20),
    sDate       DATE,
    eDate       DATE,
    Budget      NUMBER(7,2),
    maxStaff    NUMBER(2)
);
```

You will also have to use quotes every time you call it in a query. I recommend just changing that column to something else (maybe `DESCRIPTION`?)

Comment: A warning: Once you do this, `"Desc"` is case sensitive, unlike the other column names.

Comment: You are correct. It is recommended to not use these type of identifiers if it can be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Since DESC is a reserved word, you would have to enclose it in double quotes.

However, I would not recommend using reserved words for fields names, perhaps change to description or something similar

Answer (score 1):

As already said several times, the error is caused here by the use of a reserved keyword *unquoted* as an identifier. For sake of completeness:

- Oracle has an impressive [list of reserved keywords](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm).
- Unquoted identifiers are internally converted upper-case by Oracle.
- Quoted identifiers are case-sensitive

So:

> CREATE TABLE T (DESC INT);
>
> ***ORA-00904: : invalid identifier** as `DESC` is a keyword*

> CREATE TABLE T (Desc INT);
>
> ***ORA-00904: : invalid identifier** same reason as unquoted identifiers are converted all upper-case*

> CREATE TABLE T ("DESC" INT);
>
> ***Table created** by using quotes, `"DESC"` is no longer recognized as a reserved keyword*
>
> INSERT INTO T("Desc") VALUES (1);
>
> ***ORA-00904: "Desc": invalid identifier** Quoted identifiers are case-sensitive. `"DESC"` is not the same columns as `"Desc"`*
>
> INSERT INTO T("DESC") VALUES (1);
>
> ***1 row(s) inserted***

That being said, you should avoid using a keyword as an identifier...